# Блочные элементы в 3 колонки

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Есть набор блочный элементов с разной высотой. Как можно разместить их в 3 колонки, чтоб направление блоков было сверху вниз и блоки равномерно разделились по колонкам?

Comment: добавьте пример кода

Comment: [Masonry](https://masonry.desandro.com/)?

Answer (score 1):

```js
document.body.innerHTML = Array(3 + Math.random() * 20 | 0).fill().map((u,i) => `<div style='height:${Math.random() * 70 | 0}px'>${i+1}</div>`).join('')
```

```css
body {
  -moz-column-count: 3;
  column-count: 3;
  -moz-column-gap: 1em;
  column-gap: 1em;
}

div {
  min-height: 2em;
  background: silver;
  page-break-inside: avoid;
  break-inside: avoid;
}

div:nth-child(odd) {
  background: antiquewhite;
}
```